# Binding visibility of a control to 'Count' of an IEnumerable

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a list of objects contained in an IEnumerable<>.
I would like to set the visibility of a control based on the count of this list. I have tried:

```
 Visibility="{Binding MyList.Count>0?Collapsed:Visible, Mode=OneWay}"
```

But this doesn't work. I tried binding MyList.Count to the text in a text block to ensure that the count value was correct, and it is. It just doesn't seem to set the visibility correctly.

Comment: It looks like you could use this: http://www.11011.net/wpf-binding-expressions

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You cannot use logical or code-expressions in bindings (it expects a [`PropertyPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.propertypath.aspx)). Either use a [converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converter.aspx) or triggers, which is what i would do:

```
<YourControl.Style>                     
    <Style TargetType="YourControl">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyList.Count}" Value="0">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</YourControl.Style>
```

*(You can of course refactor the style into a [resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.resources.aspx) if you wish.)*

Comment: thank you this is great - would you know how one could refactor this into a resource element so that you can pass in difference Lists as parameters?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon: Well, this is difficult to do if the property on the data context is not the same, bindings are rather static unfortunately. If you have the option you could create some convention so that the path works with various data contexts, an interface so to speak that the data context implements, providing a list property that always has the same name.

Comment: @BKSpurgeon: There is the option to construct binding paths more or less dynamically using markup extensions but they probably execute at style creation time rather than application so that probably also leads nowhere.

Comment: I have a similar problem and use code similar to those from H.B. Anyway it works only the first time, when the control is loaded. But not if the listbox elements are removed or added. Is there something else that could be wrong?

Comment: @EmanueleBenedetti: Does your list fire change notifications? `Count` has to be a dependency property (usually only used for UI elements) or the list class has to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. If you use an `ObservableCollection` that should work.

Comment: @H.B. I'm using a classic `List<>`. I'll try with an `ObservableCollection`.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

There is three ways:

1. to use Triggers mentioned by H.B.
2. to use convertors by implementing IValueConverter in a class and setting the Converter property of Binding to an instance of IValueConverter in that class
3. to define a property in your ViewModel to directly return the Visibility state.

You could always use Triggers method and it always is a good approach. The third method is useful(and is best) when you are using MVVM pattern (and you are not restricting yourself from referencing UI related assemblies in your ViewModel) 
I suggest using Triggers, but if you dont want to make your xaml dirty by that much markup codes use converters.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a converter, which converts the Count property to a Visibility value, or perhaps a new "HasItems" boolean property to a Visibility value. We use something, for example, called boolToVisibilityConvert, to handle jobs like this.

I can give you more precise details, if you need them.