# Is there a way to hide a ListView in xaml?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, visibility

I have following problem. My ListView has a gray background and when the ListView is empty, you can see a small gray line on the window. This looks ugly and so I want to hide the whole ListView when it is empty to avoid this.

I searched if there is a style property to do this, but the only stuff I found is how to hide a ListViewItem or the ListViewHeader. Has someone an idea to solve this, there has to be something.

Comment: You can have a style trigger, to either set visibility to collapsed, or set the height of the listbox to 0 pixels. Both will have the same effect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a `Converter` that returns `Visibility.Collapsed` when your `ItemsSource` referenced collection is empty.

For example:

```
<ListView ItemSource="{Binding MyCollection}" Visibility="{Binding MyCollection, Converter={StaticResource EmptyCollectionConverter}}"/>
```

Your `IValueConverter.Convert()` implementation would look something like:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) 
{
    var coll = value as IEnumerable<object>;
    return (coll.Count() > 0) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

**UPDATE:** From [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7562862/binding-visibility-of-a-control-to-count-of-an-ienumerable) on how to bind to `Collection.Count` using a Style:

```
<YourControl.Style>                     
  <Style TargetType="YourControl">
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyList.Count}" Value="0">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
</YourControl.Style>
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, this is the right thing i want to do. Do you think it would be posible to solve this problem also in xaml with <style> and <trigger>?

Comment: `if(coll != null) return  ...`

Comment: Your second answer is just what i wanted. i will mark this as my answer because it's more detailed than the other one.

Answer (score 2):

```
<ListView ItemSource="{Binding MyCollection}">
 <ListView.Style>
   <Style TargetType="ListView">
     <Style.Triggers>
       <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="False">
         <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"></Setter>
       </Trigger>
     </Style.Triggers>
   </Style>
 </ListView.Style>

 ...

</ListView>
```